# Dump data to Data Frame and then plot

Tags: r, csv

I've been working on a sleep analysis project for a while and now that I have some data gathered I'd like to do something. First of all, I have registered the movement of my sleep for a while and now is on a `.csv` file like so:

```
0:58    1:08    1:18    1:28    1:38    1:48    1:58
3096    4062    903     113     1331    76      521
0:30    0:40    0:50    1:00    1:10    1:20    1:30
4081    1661    1198    70      841     1052    76
0:47    0:57    1:07    1:17    1:27    1:37    1:47
2327    1823    1354    1547    64      75      84
```

The first row is the time in 10 minutes intervals and the second one is the quantity of movement. Each pair of lines is a night of sleep and the data continues until the wake up time arrives.

Now, I have to import the data to R and then work with it. I've imported the data by using the `read.csv()` function. But now I'm stuck, I guess I'll have to use a data frame to store the data because the two types of data I have one is time and the other one is an integer number. I've worked with arrays and matrices and I cannot really understand how a data frame would really fit in this program. In a case I get to understand data frames I don't know how to work with arrays/data frames of different sizes because each night has a different length depending on how much I've slept. I'd like to plot a timeline of the average night sleep time with the average movement.

I would like to know if my assumption of using data frames is correct and how would I work with arrays of different length to create the mean of all of them.

Thank you in advance!

---

**EDIT**

Using @Pierre Lafortune's code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <-read.csv('/Users/jdmg718/Dropbox/GitHub/SleepAnalysisWithR/Movement.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
s <- split(df, rep(1:2, nrow(df)/2))
newdf <- as.data.frame(sapply(s, function(u) unlist(t(u))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(newdf) <- c('Time', 'Movements')
newdf[,2] <- as.numeric(newdf[,2])

ggplot(newdf, aes(x=Time, y=Movements, group=1)) + geom_line()
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
  largo de datos no es múltiplo de la variable de separación
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introducidos por coerción
```

Comment: Quite difficult to understand what you are asking without an [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html) ... When you do `a <- read.csv("yourdata.csv")`, the resulting object `a` is a `data.frame`. Usually, `R` interprets correctly whether you variables are of the `factor`, `integer` or `numeric` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the data by type. Then you can create the charts that you need:

```
df <- read.csv('sleep.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
s <- split(df, rep(1:2, nrow(df)/2))
newdf <- as.data.frame(sapply(s, function(u) unlist(t(u))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(newdf) <- c('Time', 'Movements')
newdf[,2] <- as.numeric(newdf[,2])
```

**Line Graph**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(newdf, aes(x=Time, y=Movements, group=1)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure to set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to get the graph, I've added to the post the code and the errors. Thank you!

Comment: No, do I have to add something to the previous code you provided? For example, what is `function(u)` inside `sapply()`.

Comment: It is an anonymous function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96833/discussion-between-pierre-lafortune-and-jdmg718).

Comment: You could also add `newdf$Time <- as.POSIXct(newdf$Time, format="%H:%M")` before making the plot in order to get better time spacings.